# Monopoly Chance Card

Tags: monopoly

In my monopoly game there is one chance card that reads "Advance to Illinois Avenue". It does not mention whether you collect money if you pass go. The rest of the cards that tell you to advance, specify whether or not you collect money. Do I get to collect on Illinois Avenue?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. “Advance to Illinois Ave” just means to move forward normally until you are at Illinois Ave. If you pass go you collect $200 like normal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you pass Go, you collect $200. See the [monopoly wiki](https://monopoly.fandom.com/wiki/Chance):

> Advance to Illinois Ave. {Avenue}. [Advance to Trafalgar Square] If you pass Go, collect $200. {Second sentence omitted.} (Mr. Monopoly has tied a cloth bundle onto his cane to make a bindle, carried over his right shoulder, and is smoking a cigar)

Answer (score 0):

Illinois Avenue is on the 24th square of the board. Two of the Chance squares are number 7 and number 22. From those, you advance 17 and 2 spaces respectively without passing Go, and to not collect $200.

One chance square is the 36th on the board. You cannot "advance" from 36 to 24, so you need to advance four squares to Go, (thereby "passing" it), and then another 24 squares to Illinois. In this one instance, you DO pass Go and collect $200.